# Reactjs props is not working fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var Works = function welcome(props) {
  return <h1> Hello, {props.name} </h1>;
}

/*function welcome() {
  return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
}*/

const element = (<div>
    <Works name="Luffy" />
</div>);

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If I replace the Works component with the commented section which has no props passed into it, it gives error, I need to know why it happens where while using class we directly use this.props. Why not here?

Comment: because it's **Stateless Functional Component** check the [**SO DOC for more details**](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/6588/stateless-functional-components/28223/stateless-functional-component#t=201707201028091144259) also check the [**React DOC**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the name of the component after Function:

```
function Works(props) {
    return <h1 > Hello, { props.name } < /h1>;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i dont want to pass props as parameter,how can i access using this.props as we do inside class component

Comment: As said above, that is a stateless component and props will be an argument, you can define the proptypes by doing Works.propTypes=blahblahblah, but you can not use this.props

Answer (score 1):

Because in here you are not calling the props,

```
/*function welcome() {
  return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
}*/
```

the code should be like this

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

Full code here

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

const element = <Welcome name="Luffy" />;

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: i know,but as in class as it works with this.props.name why here not works